# Fill data from database to Word (Django Python)

Tags: python, django

I don't know how to get data and fill into my word template. It's actually a long list, and I need to fill it on my table on word document. Am I doing it right? Here is my code:

*views.py*

```
def save_sample_details(request):
    sample = SampleList.objects.all()
    doc = DocxTemplate("lab_management/word/sample_template.docx")

    context = {
        'SNAME' : sample.sample_name,
        'STYPE' : sample.sample_type,
        'HVER' : sample.hardware_version,
        'SVER' : sample.software_version,
        'CS' : sample.config_status,
        'NUM' : sample.number,
        'SNUM' : sample.sample_number,
    }

    doc.render(context)
    doc.save('lab_management/word/sample.docx')

    return redirect('/lab/sample/details/')
```

*models.py*

```
class SampleList(models.Model):
    sample_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    sample_type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    hardware_version = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    software_version = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    config_status = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sample_number = models.CharField(max_length=17)
```

So if I run this, it shows
*'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'sample_name'* etc.

Comment: Can you show your sample `model`?

Comment: Are you trying to add everything from `SampleList` model to word?

Comment: .all() returns a QuerySet rather than an instance of an object - you want an instance of an object, not a QuerySet - there's more than one way to do this, check out my answer below for a couple of options. You'll need to decide how to determine which SampleList you want to add to the Word doc.

Comment: What is your desired result? As other's explain, you are getting a QuerySet. You have two options: iterate over the query set to generate the document. This would work well if you are populating a table or list inside the document. If you just want one object, you need a way to determine which one. Usually this is done with the primary key as part of the route. Which of these do you want?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice so what if I want more than one object? I just realize my code can just  get one object, which means i only have one on my list. How can I get the others?

Comment: @ilyasbbu yes, like a list. I have a word template with table. I wanted it to fill in to the table.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting all `SampleList` objects when you call `SampleList.objects.all()` so this is returning a `QuerySet` of zero or more objects, rather than a single object - which is what you want.

Instead you should get the single `SampleList` object you want: for example  `sample = SampleList.objects.get(id=1)` or another example - to get the first object in the `QuerySet` you could do `sample = SampleList.objects.all()[0]` (but if the `QuerySet` is empty you'll get an index error). You didn't specify how you want to determine which SampleList to put in the Word doc, but you can specify any filters in the `.get()` properties.

Django has some pretty good documentation covering querysets:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as:

```py
def save_sample_details(request):
    sample_list = SampleList.objects.all()
    doc = DocxTemplate("lab_management/word/sample_template.docx")

    context_list = []
    for sample in sample_list:
        context = {
            'SNAME' : sample.sample_name,
            'STYPE' : sample.sample_type,
            'HVER' : sample.hardware_version,
            'SVER' : sample.software_version,
            'CS' : sample.config_status,
            'NUM' : sample.number,
            'SNUM' : sample.sample_number,
        }
        context_list.append(context)

    doc.render(context_list)
    doc.save('lab_management/word/sample.docx')

    return redirect('/lab/sample/details/')
```

You should be iterating in the `context_list` in the doc as well.

(Assuming you are using `docxtpl` library)

Comment: So how should I work my word template? I used {{xxx}}. It actually populate the table, but it only show one row of data.

Comment: Share the template in question too

Comment: https://ucarecdn.com/f1fc3838-e1b5-4abb-95d7-e9a143d257aa/ here

Answer (score 0):

I have answered my question. Thank you for the help!

*views.py*

```
def save_sample_details(request):
    sample = SampleList.objects.all()[0:15]
    template = DocxTemplate("lab_management/word/sample_template.docx")

    context = {
        'headers' : ['SNAME', 'STYPE', 'HVER', 'SVER', 'CS', 'NUM', 'SNUM'],
        'list': [],
    }

    alist = ['a']

    for i in alist: 
        for samples in sample:
            content= [samples.sample_name, samples.sample_type, samples.hardware_version,
                      samples.software_version, samples.config_status, samples.number, 
                      samples.sample_number ]
            context['list'].append(content)

    template.render(context)
    template.save('lab_management/word/sample.docx')
    return redirect('/lab/sample/details/')
```

*sample_template.docx*
[image]